# cpupower utility linux - how to get a list of available frequencies

Tags: linux, fedora

I am trying to get a list of available frequencies for my cpu using the cpupower tool.

I am executing following command-

```
cpupower -c 0,1,4,5 frequency-info
```

This gives me much information but I need to see a list of available frequencies to which I can set these CPUs to.

On older versions of Fedora, I used to do this

```
$ cat /system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
2201000 2200000 2100000 2000000 1800000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1300000 1200000 1100000
```

but on Fedora 20, cpufreq is obsolete. I googled and found that cpupower has same functionality like cpufreq.
How do you use it to get a list of available frequencies?

Comment: not sure about Fedora, but on some other linux systems you can get the list from some field out of `sudo sysctl -a`

Comment: Thanks Pavel. But it did not give me the information I need.

Answer (score 2):

`cpupower frequency-info`

should give you your info